# Is there a clean way to allocate a variable size object on the stack, if the size is known at compile time?

Tags: c++

Consider the following code, which attempts to allocate an object containing a variable-length array on the stack.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct ContainVarLen {
    int normal;
    int varlen[];
};


int main(){
    ContainVarLen c;
}
```

Suppose I know at compile time that I need exactly 8 bytes of data in the `varlen` object.

**Is there a syntax to specify that I want this additional 8-byte allocation?**

I think declaring a byte array right before the object seems like a hack.

Comment: `alloca` is non-portable, but should work on the platforms that support it.

Comment: make it a `std::array` and provide the size as a template parameter?  Perhaps `ContainVarLen` then needs to be templatized with that parameter ... (Though you need C++11 for this.)

Comment: to go with your edit, I suppose you could wrap it in a normal C++ union, where the alternate is your fixed-size byte array.

Comment: `int varlen[];` is not permitted in C++

Comment: `int varlen[8 / sizeof(int)];` would solve your problem as stated.  I guess you have some other condition you didn't mention, otherwise you would have done this already?

Comment: "I think declaring a byte array right before the object seems like a hack" - plus it won't work in general: a) some stacks grow up others grow down, and b) compilers can reorder the stack frame as they please.

Comment: You mention that you want an eight-byte array but you declare the type of varlen to be of type "int". If you know you want bytes, you would use a type of char or unsigned char. I would suggest using std::array<char,8> if you really only want 8 bytes.

Comment: @jbruni, In a given instance, I want 8 bytes (enough to hold two ints), but maybe in a different instance I want 12 bytes.

Comment: @merlin2011 Sizes of ints are variable and architecture dependent. Look in <cstdint> for some symbols that map to explicit object sizes. Forgot to mention: Compilers will also align and pad arrays based on the natural access method of an object. Because of that, you might end up with some "air" in the structure unless you use a pragma to disable alignment. Be prepared to deal with SIGBUS errors if you do misaligned access, though.

Answer (score 5):

```
template <std::size_t NBytes>
class ContainVarLen
{
    int normal;
    int varlen[NBytes / sizeof(int)];
};
```

Now instantiate with any constexpr:

```
constexpr long fib(const int x)
{
    return x <= 1 ? 1 : fib(x - 1) + fib(x - 2);
}

int main()
{
    ContainVarLen<fib(7)> c;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thats they way (but with a non-type integer parameter, and I think he wants to specify bytes)

Comment: That recursion is too fancy for me to figure out anyway!

Comment: @ChristopherOicles - fixed

Comment: Ahh.  And I was confused that the Fibonacci sequence might have had something to do with figuring out bytes or something...haha.  I guess the user is screwed when the byte count is not zero (mod sizeof(int))

Comment: @ChristopherOicles - geez, toss in a gratuitous cookie just to make the answer interesting and introduce a bug or potential usage pitfall.  I should know that ...

Comment: I upvoted a long time ago -- this is just revenge for duplicating my answer before I could post it.

Comment: IMO the template parameter should be the number of `int`s, or the size of the array should be rounded up (e.g `(NBytes + sizeof(int) - 1)/sizeof(int)`).

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard, portable C++ syntax for this.

Some compilers may offer their own non-standard extensions, that can sometimes be used where portability is not a factor.

For example, with gcc I would do something like this:

```
struct ContainVarLen {
    int normal;
    int *varlen;
};

int foo(size_t n) {

    int varlen_buf[n];

    ContainVarLen c;
    c.varlen=varlen_buf;
}
```

One other possibility that also comes to mind, is to use [alloca(3)](http://manpages.courier-mta.org/htmlman3/alloca.3.html) together with placement new.

Comment: this is a run-time solution, not a compile time solution, though, as the OP requested.

Comment: @davidbak There is no compile-time solution, as the first paragraph of this answer notes